# azure VM staging to production

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine, azure-deployment

I am currently trying to figure out the **best architecture** for my **Azure VMs**.

I have a production website that is hosted in **IIS** in **2 VMs** with a **load-balancer** over them, this is called **Prod1** and for now is the live site.

I also have the exact same setup as my "staging" (called **Prod2**) environment, obviously this is not live .

I wish to deploy to **Prod2**, test and when happy switch it to live. Thereby making **Prod1** not live.

Now i can simply drop the TTL and re-point the A record on the sites Domain name to the public IP of **Prod2s** load balancer.

But is there a better way of doing this to enable faster switching between these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Azure Traffic Manager** would be my suggestion for a seamless **blue-green deployment**.

For your workloads that are running in Azure, the recommendation is to setup the Blue environment, which has the old code, and Green environment, which has the new code, in separate **Azure Resource Groups**.

If the endpoint is external, you can use any continuous integration and deployment tool to manage and deploy the two environments.

Once you have the environments ready you can create a Traffic Manager profile using the Azure portal, PowerShell, or CLI, with weighted round-robin as the routing method and add the endpoints corresponding to these environments.

See Dilip's full post [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/blue-green-deployments-using-azure-traffic-manager/).